# selecting input not working for [plcaeholder="Email"]' correctly : jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the input element with a specific attribute (required, placeholder). It works fine for the required but not for other 2.

```
<div id="divId">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" required />
   <button> Submit</button>
</div>

   <button> Submit</button>
</div>

This is in site.js file

    $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#divId input[plcaeholder="Email"]').css('background-color', 'red');
 $('#divId input:placeholder]').css('background-color', 'red');


    $('#divId input:required').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

My question is why does it not work for these 2:

```
$('#divId input[plcaeholder="Email"]').css('background-color', 'red');
 $('#divId input:placeholder]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

but works for

```
 $('#divId input:required').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Comment: Wrong spell **input[plcaeholder="Email"** typo issue **plcaeholder** so correct like this **$('#divId input[placeholder="Email"]')**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typo's.

```
$('#divId input[plcaeholder="Email"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

should be

```
$('#divId input[placeholder="Email"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

also

```
$('#divId input:placeholder]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

should be

```
$('#divId input[placeholder]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

---

Note that this line:

```
$('#divId input[placeholder]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

will give any input element that has a placeholder attribute a red background (as long as it is a child of the `#divID` element).

so you wouldn't need

```
$('#divId input[placeholder="Email"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

unless you want to give inputs with the "Email" placeholder a specific background color that is different for other input elements that have placeholders.

Also, to further improve your code, I suggest you use label elements with your input elements rather than using placeholders as the input labels.

Additionally, your "email" input should have `type="email"` rather than `type="text"`

Furthermore, you don't need to use jQuery for all this. You easily accomplish this with CSS.

```
#divId input[placeholder] {
   background-color: red;
}
```